# Estimating regression paths in lavaan, df and test statistics

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am trying to compare structural equation models using lavaan in R.
I have 4 latent variables, three of which are being estimated by 8 observed variables and one of which is being estimated by 2 observed variables.

When I run the measurement model, the test user model has 293 degrees of freedom with 58 model parameters. When I run the structural model, with three additional regression paths estimated, I receive the same model statistics with the same number of degrees of freedom (293) and the same number of model parameters (58).

Because the models are identical, and I try to compare them with anova, there are no degrees of freedom difference, and no chi-square difference, because it is the same model output.
So, I receive the following error

> Warning message: In lavTestLRT(object = object, ..., model.names =
> NAMES) :   lavaan WARNING: some models have the same degrees of
> freedom

semPaths is showing the regression coefficients estimated, and the output for parameter estimates are showing the regression coefficients for the structural model, but the fit indices (AIC, BIC, etc.), chi-square, and degrees of freedom are identical.

I thought I had simply put the wrong model in the summary function, but no, that was not it.

I am trying not to be a dolt, but I cannot figure out why lavaan is giving me exactly the same df and chi-square when I am estimating three additional paths/parameters.
Any insight is welcomed. Again, I apologize of I am missing the obvious.

Here is the code:

```
# Pre-Post Measurement Model 1 - (TM)
MeasTM1 <- '
 
  posttransp8 =~ post_Understand_Successful_Work + 
                post_Purpose_Assignment + 
                post_Assignment_Objectives_Course + 
                post_Instructor_Identified_Goal + 
                post_Steps_Required + 
                post_Assignment_Instructions +
                post_Detailed_Directions + 
                post_Knew_How_Evaluated
                
  
  preskills8 =~ pre_Express_Ideas_Write + 
                 pre_Express_Ideas_Speak + 
                 pre_Collaborate_Academic + 
                 pre_Analyz + pre_Synthesize + 
                 pre_Apply_New_Contexts + 
                 pre_Consider_Ethics + 
                 pre_Capable_Self_Learn
 
  postskills8 =~ post_Express_Ideas_Write + 
                 post_Express_Ideas_Speak + 
                 post_Collaborate_Academic + 
                 post_Analyz + post_Synthesize + 
                 post_Apply_New_Contexts + 
                 post_Consider_Ethics + 
                 post_Capable_Self_Learn
  
  postbelong2 =~ post_Belong_School_Commty + post_Helped_Belong_School_Commty

'

fitMeasTM1 <- sem(MeasTM1, data=TILTSEM)

summary(fitMeasTM1, standardized=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)

semPaths(fitMeasTM1, whatLabels = "std", layout = "tree")

# Pre-Post Factor Model 1 - (TM)
#Testing regression on Pre-Post Skills

FactTM1 <- '
 
#latent factors

  posttransp8 =~ post_Understand_Successful_Work + 
                post_Purpose_Assignment + 
                post_Assignment_Objectives_Course + 
                post_Instructor_Identified_Goal + 
                post_Steps_Required + 
                post_Assignment_Instructions +
                post_Detailed_Directions + 
                post_Knew_How_Evaluated
                
  
  preskills8 =~ pre_Express_Ideas_Write + 
                 pre_Express_Ideas_Speak + 
                 pre_Collaborate_Academic + 
                 pre_Analyz + pre_Synthesize + 
                 pre_Apply_New_Contexts + 
                 pre_Consider_Ethics + 
                 pre_Capable_Self_Learn
 
  postskills8 =~ post_Express_Ideas_Write + 
                 post_Express_Ideas_Speak + 
                 post_Collaborate_Academic + 
                 post_Analyz + post_Synthesize + 
                 post_Apply_New_Contexts + 
                 post_Consider_Ethics + 
                 post_Capable_Self_Learn
  
  postbelong2 =~ post_Belong_School_Commty + post_Helped_Belong_School_Commty

#regressions
  postskills8 ~ preskills8 + postbelong2 + posttransp8
'

fitFactTM1 <- sem(FactTM1, data=TILTSEM)

summary(fitFactTM1, standardized=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)

semPaths(fitFactTM1, whatLabels = "std", layout = "tree")

anova(fitMeasTM1,fitFactTM1)
```

Here is the model output for the two models (to show that they are identical):

=========================Pre-Post Measurement Model 1 - (TM)=============================
Estimator                                         ML
Optimization method                           NLMINB
Number of model parameters                        58

```
                                              Used       Total
```

Number of observations                           521         591

Model Test User Model:

Test statistic                              1139.937
Degrees of freedom                               293
P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Model Test Baseline Model:

Test statistic                              4720.060
Degrees of freedom                               325
P-value                                        0.000

User Model versus Baseline Model:

Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.807
Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.786

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

Loglikelihood user model (H0)             -13335.136
Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)     -12765.167

Akaike (AIC)                               26786.271
Bayesian (BIC)                             27033.105
Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (BIC)        26849.000

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

RMSEA                                          0.074
90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.070
90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.079
P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                          0.000

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

SRMR                                           0.068

=========================Pre-Post Factor Model 1 - (TM)======================

Estimator                                         ML
Optimization method                           NLMINB
Number of model parameters                        58

```
                                              Used       Total
```

Number of observations                           521         591

Model Test User Model:

Test statistic                              1139.937
Degrees of freedom                               293
P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Model Test Baseline Model:

Test statistic                              4720.060
Degrees of freedom                               325
P-value                                        0.000

User Model versus Baseline Model:

Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.807
Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.786

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

Loglikelihood user model (H0)             -13335.136
Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)     -12765.167

Akaike (AIC)                               26786.271
Bayesian (BIC)                             27033.105
Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (BIC)        26849.000

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

RMSEA                                          0.074
90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.070
90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.079
P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                          0.000

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

SRMR                                           0.068

Comment: I tried the option suggested by @socialscientist below, using auto.cov.lv.x = TRUE, and I came out with the same result. I also tried auto.cov.lv.x = FALSE, and again, I did not receive any different results. I thought about setting constraints on the covariates, and I found the option to make the latent factors orthogonal, basically setting the covariance estimates to zero, which I assume could be specified under constraints. Using orthogonal = TRUE in the SEM function worked. It set to zero any covariates across latent factors that I did not specify in my regression equations.

Comment: You're fitting a different model, so yes - specifying a completely new model can produce different results. Hard to know what's going on without code/data. Note that setting orthogonal = T means your regression coefficients are known to be exactly 0, which makes it silly to run a regression. Similarly, the models also differ by having the latent outcome correlate with residual variances of the observed variables in one model and not in the other. These models differ by a lot more than "adding a regression" and the same factor ID in your code is likely capturing a completely different concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **aren't** using up more degrees of freedom.

One thing that makes `lavaan::sem()` dangerous to use over `lavaan::lavaan()` is that its defaults are hard to remember and/or notice. If you look at `?lavaan::sem`, you will see those defaults:

> The sem function is a wrapper for the more general lavaan function, but setting the following default options: int.ov.free = TRUE, int.lv.free = FALSE, auto.fix.first = TRUE (unless std.lv = TRUE), auto.fix.single = TRUE, auto.var = TRUE, auto.cov.lv.x = TRUE, auto.efa = TRUE, auto.th = TRUE, auto.delta = TRUE, and auto.cov.y = TRUE

You can find out what this means via `?lavOptions`:

> auto.cov.lv.x: If TRUE, the covariances of exogenous latent variables are included in the model and set free.

By default, all exogenous latent variables (i.e., all of your latent factors) are correlated in your model already.

I'm also not sure how you are identifying the 2-item factor, so I'm surprised this does not throw a warnings, unless you're ignoring it.

Comment: I voted up your answer, but regarding your last comment, the 2-indicator factor could be empirically identified if it is substantially correlated with another factor.  The possibility of empirical identification comes from correlations between indicators of different factors. Steiger (2002) provides the equations demonstrating this: https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/1082-989X.7.2.210

Comment: Can't access the paper but makes sense and this follows the literature I'm more familiar with in identification of instrumental variables models. But in that case as well you're in the silly situation: "Pray for X to be highly correlated but not too highly correlated!"